# How do I get a list of yahoo tickers for NYSE

Tags: yahoofinance

I use Yahoo finance to get financial data. How do I get a list of all the ticker symbols in NYSE, NYSEMKT and NASDAQ stock exchanges.

(Or even just one of the exchanges)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://github.com/Benny-/Yahoo-ticker-symbol-downloader

It gets its data from https://finance.yahoo.com/lookup/.

Please note: it is not possible to get all the symbols due to limitations set by Yahoo. About 75%-90% of all symbols are gathered using this script depending on type

Answer (score 1):

I am sharing list of update symbols, All are from Yahoo Only. https://github.com/stockdatalab/Stock-Exchanges-Ticker-List

We are pushing all in our github account soon you can find them on our website as well.